# How do you plot relative frequency in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, frequency

I am looking to plot the relative frequency of a bunch of numbers in Python. I need to use the `hist` function, I have looked elsewhere on this site but I haven't found anything.

I am doing the following

```
x = array ([6.36,6.34,6.36,6.73,7.36,6.73])
hist (x)
```

When I do this I get a plot of just frequency, how do I make it relative frequency?

Comment: Are you using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/)? If not, what library are you using, since this is not in standard python?

Comment: Is it not the answer for your problem ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767241/setting-a-relative-frequency-in-a-matplotlib-histogram

Comment: I am using matplotlib.pyplot

I looked at that question before and tried using normed=1 but I still didn't get it

I tried doing hist(x/x.sum()) but that reduce the values of the numbers in the x axis and does not change their frequency, so the y-axis is unchanged

Thanks for the suggestions though

Comment: Any others suggestions @larsmans

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?

Answer (score 3):

```
hist(x, density=True)
```

The keyword `density` will plot the data such that the integral  is 1 ([doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist)).  For old versions of Matplotlib you will need to use `normed` instead.

If you want the sum (not the integral) to be one

```
x = randn(30)
count,bins = np.histogram(x)
bar(bins[:-1],count,width = np.mean(np.diff(bins)))
```

Comment: `normed` is deprecated. You can use `density` instead. It makes the integral (NOT the sum) equal 1.

Comment: @root Thanks for the comment!  Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: Silly question: what's the difference between having the integral equal to 1 vs. the sum being 1?

Comment: @neither-nor Integral is the sum of the area under each bin (height times bin_width), so they are only equal if your bins are width 1.

Comment: In case of sum to be one,  I use `bar(bins[:-1],count/sum(count))`. I don't know but width argument seems to define the apparent width of the bars. https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html