# matplotlib reducing y axis by a factor to represent percent frequency

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

so i have 3 lists of fractions and i used  a histogram to show how often each fraction showed up. The problem is that there are 100000 of each and i need to reduce the y vaues by that much to get a frequency percentage. Here is my code now

```
bins = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 50)

z = np.linspace(0,1,50)
g = (lambda z: 2 * np.exp((-2)*(z**2)*(1000000000)))
w = g(z)
plt.plot(z,w)

pyplot.hist(Vrand, bins, alpha=0.5)
pyplot.hist(Vfirst, bins, alpha=0.5)
pyplot.hist(Vmin, bins, alpha=0.2)
pyplot.show()
```

it is the last chunk of code i need the y axis divided by 100000

Update:
when i try to divide by 100000 using np histograms all the values =0 except the line above

```
bins = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 50)

z = np.linspace(0,1,50)
g = (lambda z: 2 * np.exp((-2)*(z**2)*(100000)))
w = g(z)
plt.plot(z,w)

hist, bins = np.histogram(Vrand, bins)
hist /= 100000.0
widths = np.diff(bins)
pyplot.bar(bins[:-1], hist, widths)
```

Comment: I think this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767241/setting-a-relative-frequency-in-a-matplotlib-histogram

Answer (score 4):

[matplotlib histogram has](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html) a "normed" parameter that you can use to scale everything to `[0,1]` interval

```
pyplot.hist(Vrand, bins, normed=1)
```

or use `weights` parameter to scale it by different coefficient.

You can also use the retuning value of numpy `histogram` and scale it whatever you want (tested in python 3.x)

```
hist, bins = np.histogram(Vrand, bins)
hist /= 100000.0
widths = np.diff(bins)
pyplot.bar(bins[:-1], hist, widths)
```

First two solutions are in my opinion better, as we should not "reinvent the wheel" and implement by hand what is already done in library.

Comment: hmmm for some reason when i divide by 100000 i get all histograms 0

Comment: o and this problem does not happen hen i dived by one less 0

Comment: dividing by large numbers in python 2 is integer division, thus you should divide by 100000.0 (notice the "dot zero")

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would recommend you think about your style, use either `plt` or `pyplot` not both and you should include in example code some fake data to illustrate the problem and your imports.

So, the issue is that in the following example the counts are very large:

```
bins = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
data = np.random.normal(0.5, 0.1, size=100000)

plt.hist(data, bins)
plt.show()
```

[image]

You tried to fix this by dividing the bin count by an integer:

```
hist, bins = plt.histogram(data, bins)
hist_divided = hist/10000
```

The issue here is that hist is an array of `int`'s and dividing integers is tricky. For example

```
>>> 2/3
0
>>> 3/2
1
```

This is what gives you a row of `0`'s if you pick too large a value to divide by. Instead you can divide by a float as suggested by @lejlot, notice you need to divide by `10000.0` and not `10000`.

Or the other suggestion made by @lejlot just use the `normed` argument in the call to 'hist'. This rescales all the numbs in `hist` such that the sum of their squares is `1`, very useful when comparing values.

I also notice you appear to be having this issue because your plotting a line plot on the same axis as the histogram, if this line plot is outside of the `[0,1]` range you will again encounter the same issue, instead of rescale the histogram axis you should [twin the x axis](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html).

Comment: On a side note: The "ticky" integer division you are describing is only present in Python 2.x,  in 3.x you have to explicitly use the floor division operator `//` for this to happen. So in Python 3.x e.g. `1/2` will return `0.5` and `1//2` will return `0`. Also, another work-around to the integer division in Python 2.x is to include `from __future__ import division`, which gives the same behavior in Python 2.x as the default behavior in Python 3.x.

Comment: as a side note `pyplot` and `plt` are the same thing

Comment: i already imported future division :( and normed=1 for some reason gives me a range to 100 and changing the value didnt work