# producing histogram with y axis as relative frequency?

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, histogram

Today my task is to produce a histogram where the y axis is a relative frequency rather than just an absolute count. I've located another question regarding this (see: [Setting a relative frequency in a matplotlib histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767241/setting-a-relative-frequency-in-a-matplotlib-histogram)) however, when I try to implement it, I get the error message:

`'list' object has no attribute size`

despite having the exact same code given in the answer -- and despite their information also being stored in a list.

In addition, I have tried the method here(http://www.bertplot.com/visualization/?p=229) with no avail, as the output still doesn't show the y label as ranging from 0 to 1.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from tabulate import tabulate
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

precision = 100000000000

def MarkovChain(n,s) :
    """

  """
    matrix = []
    for l in range(n) :
        lineLst = []
        sum = 0
        crtPrec = precision
        for i in range(n-1) :
            val = random.randrange(crtPrec)
            sum += val
            lineLst.append(float(val)/precision)
            crtPrec -= val
        lineLst.append(float(precision - sum)/precision)
        matrix2 = matrix.append(lineLst)

    print("The intial probability matrix.")    
    print(tabulate(matrix2))
    baseprob = []
    baseprob2 = []
    baseprob3 = []
    baseprob4 = []

    for i in range(1,s): #changed to do a range 1-s instead of 1000

        #must use the loop variable here, not s (s is always the same)
        matrix_n = np.linalg.matrix_power(matrix2, i)
        baseprob.append(matrix_n.item(0))
        baseprob2.append(matrix_n.item(1))
        baseprob3.append(matrix_n.item(2))

    baseprob = np.array(baseprob)
    baseprob2 = np.array(baseprob2)
    baseprob3 = np.array(baseprob3)
    baseprob4 = np.array(baseprob4)

    # Here I tried to make a histogram using the plt.hist() command, but the normed=True doesn't work like I assumed it would.
    '''    
  plt.hist(baseprob, bins=20, normed=True)
  plt.show()
  '''

    #Here I tried to make a histogram using the method from the second link in my post.
    # The code runs, but then the graph that is outputted isn't doesn't have the relative frequency on the y axis.
    '''
   n, bins, patches = plt.hist(baseprob, bins=30,normed=True,facecolor = "green",)
   y = mlab.normpdf(bins,mu,sigma)
   plt.plot(bins,y,'b-')
   plt.title('Main Plot Title',fontsize=25,horizontalalignment='right')
   plt.ylabel('Count',fontsize=20)
   plt.yticks(fontsize=15)
   plt.xlabel('X Axis Label',fontsize=20)
   plt.xticks(fontsize=15)
   plt.show()
   '''
    # Here I tried to make a histogram using the method seen in the Stackoverflow question I mentioned.
    # The figure that pops out looks correct in terms of the axes, but no actual data is posted. Instead the error below is shown in the console.
    # AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'size'


    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.hist(baseprob, weights=np.zeros_like(baseprob)+1./ baseprob.size)
    n, bins, patches = ax.hist(baseprob, bins=100, normed=1, cumulative=0)
    ax.set_xlabel('Bins', size=20)
    ax.set_ylabel('Frequency', size=20)
    ax.legend
    plt.show()


    print("The final probability matrix.")
    print(tabulate(matrix_n))
    matrixTranspose = zip(*matrix_n)
    evectors = np.linalg.eig(matrixTranspose)[1][:,0]
    print("The steady state vector is:")
    print(evectors)






MarkovChain(5, 1000)
```

The methods I tried are each commented out, so to reproduce my errors, make sure to erase the comment markers.

As you can tell, I'm really new to Programming. Also this is *not* for a homework assignment in a computer science class, so there are no moral issues associated with just providing me with code.

Answer (score 1):

The expected input to `matplotlib` functions are usually numpy arrays, which have the methods `nparray.size`. Lists do not have size methods so when `list.size` is called in the `hist` function, this causes your error. You need to convert, using `nparray = np.array(list)`. You can do this after the loop where you build the lists with append, something like,

```
baseprob = []
baseprob2 = []
baseprob3 = []
baseprob4 = []

for i in range(1,s): #changed to do a range 1-s instead of 1000

 #must use the loop variable here, not s (s is always the same)
     matrix_n = numpy.linalg.matrix_power(matrix, i)
     baseprob.append(matrix_n.item(0))
     baseprob2.append(matrix_n.item(1))
     baseprob3.append(matrix_n.item(2))

 baseprob = np.array(baseprob)
 baseprob2 = np.array(baseprob2)
 baseprob3 = np.array(baseprob3)
 baseprob4 = np.array(baseprob4)
```

EDIT: minimal hist example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
baseprob = np.random.randn(1000000)
ax.hist(baseprob, weights=np.zeros_like(baseprob)+1./ baseprob.size, bins=100)
n, bins, patches = ax.hist(baseprob, bins=100, normed=1, cumulative=0, alpha = 0.4)
ax.set_xlabel('Bins', size=20)
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency', size=20)
ax.legend
plt.show()
```

which gives,

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried implementing it and I got the error:

`ValueError: input must be square array`.

According to the console log, it fails on line 41, which is: 

`matrix_n = np.linalg.matrix_power(matrix2, i)`

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: pastebin link for code and output http://pastebin.com/WAHQfuYy

Comment: Also I noticed something odd: If I change `matrix2` to just `matrix` on line 41, a figure appears, but it's not at all the correct figure; it still has the axis as an absolute count rather than a relative one.  imgur link to figure: http://i.imgur.com/9xoTsHb.png

Comment: Your use of `matrix2 = matrix.append(lineLst)` is not correct. The `append` method adds `lineLst` to the list `matrix ` and doesn't return anything. Therefore matrix2 is empty... What should the "correct" distribution look like? Gaussian? I think you need to simplify what you're doing. For example if you call `plt.plot(baseprob)`, you'll see it fluctuates and decays to a constant over the first few values so you get a large peak (i.e. the hist is correct for the data). I've added a minimal hist example.

Comment: `normed` is deprecated. You can use `density` instead. It makes the integral (NOT the sum) equal 1.